# How to make update on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I am studying how to use GitHub to collaborate with other people.
I have already set up Collaborators for one of my project and they have been able to download it.

But I don't know how to go for the next step. In other words, after they make their contribution; how are they supposed to upoad the result of their work, so that I can get it?

Comment: They might work in a branch and create a `pull-request`. Then commit everything into that branch and when they say it's done you check the code and merge the branch.

Comment: OK thanks. That is probably basic if one is used to work with GitHub, but not necessarily the first time. Would you know of a step by step guide to do that? Using GitHub-Desktop. If not using the command line.

Comment: https://guides.github.com/ and/or to get started: https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/ as soon as you get the basics it will not matter if you use the command line or GUI

Comment: Yes indeed, by following the guides I have been able to make an update to a test project. But everything is not quite clear yet. I follow the process of creating-a-branch -> editing-something -> creating-a-pull-request -> merging-the-branch. Then I delete the branch since it is no more needed. Apparently it works, but I can still see the deleted branch after, so it doesn't seem to be really deleted.

Comment: You can do `git branch -a` to list local and remote branches. There you will see that your branch is still visible but only local. So what you want to do now is `git fetch origin --prune` then it will sync your local repository with the remote one. Means if you delete the branch on remote (via browser button) you still have a copy of the branch on your system. With the mentioned command it will update.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes indeed, by following the guides I have been able to make an update to a test project.
>
> But everything is not quite clear yet.
> I follow the process of `creating-a-branch -> editing-something -> creating-a-pull-request -> merging-the-branch`.
> Then I delete the branch since it is no more needed. **Apparently it works, but I can still see the deleted branch after, so it doesn't seem to be really deleted**.

Starting July 2019, using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), as part of its [epic "branch pruning"](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Aepic%3Abranch-pruner%20) and its 2.1.0 release, will prune those remote tracking branches for you.

Branches that have been merged and deleted on GitHub.com will now be pruned after two weeks.

See [desktop/desktop issue 750](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/750):

> We decided in taking a very conservative posture that we would only delete branches that aren't actively in use (hence the 14 days requirement) and don't have anything on them that's ahead of the default branch on GitHub. This combination, in addition to the branch being deleted on GitHub.com, seems relatively uncontroversial, but we're definitely going to listen to feedback we receive in the weeks and months after this ships to make sure it aligns with people's expectations and isn't overly aggressive.
>
> Because we've taken an extremely conservative approach here, we don't intend to provide the ability to toggle it as a setting.
> If you use a particularly branch frequently, this will never prune that branch, and it's restricted only to branches where there is no additional work that hasn't been merged into the default branch on GitHub.
> In other words, we set this up intentionally such that users should never lose any work, which is our primary concern when deleting things. Hope that makes sense, and appreciate the feedback.